# ADF - "errors" element in output activity file - how is it read and evaluated if exists

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have two Copy activities in my pipeline. First is executed OK, and second failed. When I look up at output files for each of them for the first one (the successful one) I see "errors" element as follows

```
"errors": [],
```

which is Ok since no error happened.

For the second one (which is failed) I also see "errors" element but this one has elements inside as follows:

```
 "errors": [
        {
            "Code": 9013,
            "Message": "Some text - erased for the simplicity"
            "EventType": 0,
            "Category": 5,
            "Data": {},
            "MsgId": null,
            "ExceptionType": null,
            "Source": null,
            "StackTrace": null,
            "InnerEventInfos": []
        }
    ],
```

Those 2 activities are chained "On Completion" and at the end there is IF activity which checks if there is error for any of the copy activities and doing something if there is actually an error. The If True contition is evaluated as follows (for second activity)

```
@greaterOrEquals(length(activity('Second Copy Activity').output.errors),1)
```

It works OK meaning if second copy activity is not executed OK this will trigger activity under true condition in IF activity and do something. If second copy activity is executed OK it will fall under false condition in IF activity (which is OK) and will do something accordingly.

My question is related to expression  `@greaterOrEquals(length(activity('Second Copy Activity').output.errors),1)` and what do I actually check here - is it array length that I check or string length? Since this is working fine for me I just want to be sure that I communicate to others correct logic. For sure if someone think that I should do it other way (meaning to set up differently dynamic expression) it's more than welcome.

Thanks in advance.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [empty() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#empty) to check whether errors element is empty or not. Expression:

```
@empty(activity('Second Copy Activity').output.errors)
```